# Using redux action type in a React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have this code below:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_LIST":
        // update state
        break;
    case "GET_LIST_SUCCESS":
        // update state
        break;
    case "GET_LIST_ERROR":
        // update state
        break;
    default:
        return state;
}
```

Before this, I've already set-up some action creators (with a thunk middleware for async requests). So the flow would be either `GET_LIST > GET_LIST_SUCCESS` OR `GET_LIST > GET_LIST_ERROR`.

Now in my React component, I want to do something depending on which action type was dispatched in the end (either success or error).

Is it a good practice to use the action type themselves or should I just use the store state for my condition? In this example, my store would have an `error` property, which I can use to detect whether there's an error or not.

So it's either (using action type):

```
if (actiontype === "GET_LIST_SUCCESS") {
  // do something
}
```

OR (using the store state)

```
if (this.props.list.length > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Which is a better practice and why?

Comment: I would use a property in redux to set the success and failure and in the component I'll check the redux property and list length(what if the request is succeeded and list returned is null)

Answer (score 1):

Just my opinion, but one advantage of using Redux over storing data in component state is that you separate the concern of how to handle data updating from view layer (React) to Redux; React component should only know if the data has been changed, not how it is changed. This de-couples the data layer and view layer in frontend, and helpful when you need to execute a chain of actions to update state (e.g. fetching from API).

If you want to expose current Redux action type to React component, you have to log the action somewhere in your app, since I don't think Redux exposes current action to view layer. In addition, this also reveal too much info of how Redux handles data flow.

Common practice is saving fetching state in boolean, and error log, e.g. `isFetching` and `fetchListError`, update those values along the fetching process, and pass those value to view layer for display.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, we have react app with components and redux app with store. We use 
 another library react-redux to bind react app and redux app. React-redux helps to use redux store state in react component and helps to dispatch actions to redux store from react component.

For handling asynchronous operation libraries like Redux-thunk is used and depending on the result of the asynchronous operation, these libraries dispatch action.

**Answer to your question**: React is not aware of which action was dispatched in Redux store as it is handled by thunk middleware. But using React-redux, React can know what is the current Redux store state after the action was dispatched by thunk middleware. So I think you shoud go with the second option. First option might be possible but it will need alot of hacking than simply using the first one.